# Filter DataTable in Primefaces only works once

Tags: java, jsf, filter, datatable, primefaces

I'm trying to filter a dataTable using Primefaces much like [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf). (In a web browser) I type the text I want to filter by, it works once but when I remove the text I've written the result stays the same when it should go back to it's original state.

So it works once and then won't respond. (I can remove or re-type the filter text I've written but it does not affect the table anymore)

Sorry about the weird attribute names in the code, bear with me. :)

xhtml-page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="aggr" value="#{aggregationManagedBean.logiskAdressatModel}"
             widgetVar="aggrTable"
             emptyMessage="No aggr found with given criteria">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Filter:" />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="aggrTable.filter()" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
        <p:column filterBy="#{aggr.name}"> 
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name" /> 
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{aggr.name}" /> 
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AggregationManagedBean {

    private List<LogiskAdressat> logiskaAdressater;
    private DataModel<LogiskAdressat> logiskAdressatModel;

    public AggregationManagedBean() {
        logiskaAdressater = getLogiskaAdressater();
        logiskAdressatModel = new ListDataModel<LogiskAdressat>(logiskaAdressater);
    }

    private static List<LogiskAdressat> getLogiskaAdressater(){
        List<LogiskAdressat> logiskaAdressater = new ArrayList<LogiskAdressat>();

        logiskaAdressater.add(new LogiskAdressat("01 addr_id 01", "Joe"));
        logiskaAdressater.add(new LogiskAdressat("02 addr_id 02", "John"));        
        logiskaAdressater.add(new LogiskAdressat("03 addr_id 03", "Jake"));

        return logiskaAdressater;
    }

    public DataModel<LogiskAdressat> getLogiskAdressatModel() {
        return logiskAdressatModel;
    }

    public void setLogiskAdressatModel(DataModel<LogiskAdressat> adressatModel) {
        this.setLogiskAdressatModel(adressatModel);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `LogiskAdressat` **Serializable**?

If not, then try making it Serializable -

```java
public class LogiskAdressat implements Serializable {

    //....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Left the computer at work though so I'll have to get back on monday, silly me.

Comment: Wow, I did not think that was the problem. It worked, thank you very much!